# AWS credetails for jenkins ec2 plug in as environemnt variables with no public expose

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I'm using jenkinsci docker image as microservice and trying to auto fill all the ec2 plugin info with environment variables. Docker's .env files can be used to specify ami configurations info except aws credentials with out exposing in the source code. Pls help me!! if it's a good practice to have a dedicated iam user for an s3 secret file with credentails and then add the user to ec2 instance running jenkins on docker. to pull with a groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

I have used docker compose environment: variables to inject secrets as base64 encoded strings.